# Web Scraper problem[simple]: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getHTMLText(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
        r.raise_for_status() # generate error information
        r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding # could be revised to enhance the speed
        return r.next # return the HTML to other parts of the programmme
    except:
        return ""

def fillUnivKust(ulist, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for a in soup.find('li').children:
        if isinstance(a, bs4.element.Tag): # avoid String type's data
            aaa = a('div') # There are only 2 divs here in this case
            ulist.append([aaa[0].string]) # aaa[0] -> Product's name

def printUnivList(ulist, num):
    for i in range(num):
        u = ulist[i] # u already have
        print(u[i]) # print the ith product's name

def main():
    uinfo = []
    url = 'https://www.cattelanitalia.com/en/products?c=new'
    html = getHTMLText(url)
    fillUnivKust(uinfo, html)
    printUnivList(uinfo, 25)

main()
```

I tried to write a simple Python Web Scraper, the code is above, the Web Scraper only include this much code. After running it, I received an error says:

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I don't know where it is wrong.

-- Update --

I changed '''return r.next''' to '''return r.content'''

It generates this error:

IndexError: list index out of range

I don't know why again.

Comment: I see ```call back hell```. You're just making it difficult for yourself by writing all of these call back functions. If it's simple, then just keep it simple. The so-called ```call back hell``` is hard to debug for others too!

Comment: What do you mean?call back hell, what is call back hell? I'm a newbie. Please explain clearly! It's hard for newbies to understand too!

Comment: When you create nested functions that call each other, they're called ```call back hell```. Several nested functions that call each other make it difficult to debug. For a simple scraper I wouldn't use functional approach!

Comment: I wouldn't really call this 'call back hell' the style is actually nice and clean IMHO - small functions each doing one job only. The functions aren't nested - they're distinct, and they're also not calling each other - main is calling each of them in turn. Really don't see the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is comming from this line:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

The `TypeError` when initialising the `BeautifulSoup` class tells us that BeautifulSoup tried to perform a `len` operation but was unable to do so on a NoneType object. Ergo, the data passed in as the `html` argument (i.e. the first positional argument) was a `NoneType` rather than an HTML doc.

So why is the HTML a `NoneType`? That arrises from your `getHTMLText` function, specifically the line:

`return r.next`

is returning None for the URL you provided in main. The line `r = requests.get()` is returning a `requests.Response` object, and from that `.next` returns a "PreparedRequest for the next request in a redirect chain, if there is one." [[source]](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response) - i.e. not an HTML element. You probably want to update that line to:

`return r.content`

as per [this tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/)

A couple of side notes:

1. In the case that an exception is caught in `getHTMLText` you'll return an empty string, not HTML so I presume that this will also error when initialising the `BeautifulSoup`.
2. It is generally a bad idea to catch blanket exceptions - better is to catch the specific expected exception(s) to be raised in the situation, and allow all others to fail. See: [this blog post](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/)
3. Single letter variable names are often hard to use with a debugger, as certain characters have [special meanings.](https://wangchuan.github.io/coding/2017/07/12/ipdb-cheat-sheet.html) I recommend you remain your `r` variable and in general avoid single character variables names as it will make your life easier for yourself when you start using the debugger :)

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your help! However,  I tried to change "return r.next" to "return r.content", it generates this error: IndexError: list index out of range. I don't know why. Could you please help me have a look again? I reckon it is still because there is no length of the array?

Comment: np :) your issue is in this line - ` ulist.append([aaa[0].string])`  the code is assuming that aaa is a non-empty list, what happens if aaa is an empty list? you need to handle this case.

Comment: btw If this helped solve the issue please consider accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in `getHTMLText()` - try replacing `return r.next` with `return r.text`.